# How to design a searchable, versioned library of items with wildly varying properties and multiple editors?

Tags: database-design, architecture

**What I need:**

I'm designing the backend for a product library which has to satisfy the following requirements:

1. Multiple editors will be editing different items at the same time -- there has to be some kind of item-level locking.
2. Wildly varying item properties -- there are about a 100 subcategories, each of which can have 10+ item properties specific to itself.
3. The whole item store has to be versioned -- multiple changes (insertions, edits and deletions) can be made before publishing the whole set of changes to the site; unpublishing must also be possible.
4. I must be able to search all the properties and filter by some of them -- i.e. find a keyword anywhere in the library or find all products that satisfy a set of criteria -- within a data set of at least 10MB (i.e. 5000 items, 2KB each,) and possibly twice that.

The solution should either be MySQL-specific or, better yet, vendor-agnostic.

**What I've considered:**

I'm considering using a single large XML object with all the items (to satisfy **2**) stored in a database (to satisfy **3**) but that makes **1** impossible and **4** difficult. I've used something like this before, but with smaller XML objects and no item-level locking.

The other solution I'm considering is a classic database solution using a separate table for each subcategory, which makes **1** and **2** trivial, but **3** and **4** rather difficult. It's also a bit unwieldy considering the number of different subcategories and therefore number of different tables in the database, but I guess that can be automated.

Another possibility is a hybrid between the two, with a single large database table of all items. Each row would contain an XML object with all the item's properties and additionally all the filtrable properties as table fields. This solves **1**, **2** and partially solves **4** but leaves out full-text searching and still makes **3** rather difficult to achieve.

**If you've made it so far:**

I'll probably have a few weeks to solve it, which should leave enough time for discussion. I'll be very grateful for any and all thoughts and insights the SO community can provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen option 3 implemented successfully. SQL Server full text search will index XML columns

Comment: How would you solve versioning in this kind of system (i.e. the second and third solution)?

Comment: Have you seen AutoAudit (codeplex)? Perhaps you could use this?

Comment: I've added the MySQL-or-vendor-agnostic requirement. I'd rather have an universal and self-contained solution.

Comment: but you won't be implementing universally will you? You will be targeting one particular system.

Comment: Sure, MySQL. If it's MySQL-specific, so be it, but I'd still want it to be self-contained.

Comment: What kind of versioning do you need? Item-level versioning or item _set_ level versioning? In other words, when you do a "check-in" (to use the version control parlance), are you checking-in individual items, or whole sets of items? To put it another way: are items related - and do relationships need to be versioned as well?

Comment: Item set level versioning, i.e. someone creates a set of changes to a number of items and then publishes the whole set. Items can be linked to each other, but that's a secondary function, not very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 - Classic database solution as outlined by you works well for this case.

It takes care of 1, 2 [a bit difficult but you can overcome most of it by designing little gereric mannager], 3.

For point 4, I would suggest you explore using Apache Solr which can be easily integrated with RDBMS, can index data and it is 100 times more faster than SQL.

Answer (score 2):

couchbase

It meets all your requirements

1. Use multi version concurrency control to manage concurrent access to database items and to enforce consistency, but advisory locks can be used to limit access to items to one client.
2. Schema is flexible
3. Versions are simple to implement http://blog.couchbase.com/simple-document-versioning-couchdb
4. Supports map-reduce and views so you can get to the data (caveat is that queries are not adhoc)

Answer (score 1):

I think the hybrid model has the most promise.

Specifically, I would use the relational model for the data about which your application needs to be able to reason - I would include the versioning and locking logic in this relational model.

I would use XML or similar to store the data about which the application does not need to reason.

For searching and filtering, I'd use a dedicated search engine - something like Lucene or similar. I'd manage the Lucene index as part of the "publish new version" routine. You could, of course, use your database server's built-in free text searching, instead of Lucene.

I would not try to use the same data model for "transactional" logic and searching/filtering - they are different tasks, and become hard to manage with lots of schema variations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are kind of pigeonholing yourself by going straight for a relational database or an XML file for persistence. Have you considered a NoSQL or polyglot persistence layer? There are many different flavors of NoSQL with different strengths and weaknesses. Martin Fowler recently posted a great high level [overview](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nosql-intro.pdf) of NoSQL databases and polyglot persistence you may find enlightening.

I don't have any personal experience outside the realm of using a relational database for persistence, but I've done some reading about NoSQL and polyglot persistence, and I am itching to code up a solution to play around with the concept.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: The app is most probably going to run on a shared server administered by some crappy hosting service. I don't want to make things difficult for myself :)